# Disable button in angular with two conditions?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Is this possible in angular ?

```
<button type="submit" [disabled]="!validate && !SAForm.valid">Add</button>
```

I expect that if both of the conditions are true they will enable the  button.

I've already tried the above code but it's not working as expected.

Comment: it's been years since I post this one, I never thought it will be this popular.
I'm not using angular anymore but I'm using laravel 8 , vue 3 , tailwind and inertia.
Back then I'm just a junior web dev, seeing this question, give me goose bump how poor may code.

thank you for all the answered below, I really appreciate it
sorry for may poor english

Answer (score 190, accepted):

It sounds like you need an OR instead:

```
<button type="submit" [disabled]="!validate || !SAForm.valid">Add</button>
```

This will disable the button if not validate or if not SAForm.valid.

Answer (score 27):

In addition to the other answer, I would like to point out that this reasoning is also known as **the [De Morgan's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)**. It's actually more about mathematics than programming, but it is so fundamental that every programmer should know about it.

Your problem started like this:

```
enabled  = A and B
disabled = not ( A and B )
```

So far so good, but you went one step further and tried to remove the braces.
And that's a little tricky, because you have to replace the `and`/`&&` with an `or`/`||`.

```
not ( A and B ) = not(A) OR not(B)
```

Or in a more mathematical notation:

[image]

I always keep this law in mind whenever I simplify conditions or work with probabilities.

Comment: Awesome. this is one of the advantages of having more Math knowledge is you know this kind of things that are very applicable to programming.

Comment: @The.Wolfgang.Grimmer Indeed, while distributivity, associativity and commutativity are commonly known for addition and multiplication (e.g. `(a+b)*c = ac+bc` ), not enough programmers know that there are similar laws in "Boolean Algebra". On top of that, those rules are also useful for "Set Algebra" which defines rules of union, intersection, complement, which are fundamental for learning about relational databases (and SQL). And for those who studied digital electronics, they probably had to use it to re-model AND/OR/NOT logic to NAND gates. It's all about "de morgan" again and again.

Answer (score 15):

Declare a variable in component.ts and initialize it to some value

```
 buttonDisabled: boolean;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.buttonDisabled = false;
  }
```

Now in .html or in the template, you can put following code:

```
<button disabled="{{buttonDisabled}}"> Click Me </button>
```

Now you can enable/disable button by changing value of `buttonDisabled` variable.

Comment: I would use ngOnInit instead of constructor.

Answer (score 2):

I use the ternary operator, but compare if `form.valid` is true.
Ej:

```
<button mat-button color="primary" [disabled]="((formUser.valid==true) && (formColaborador.valid==true))? false:true" (click)="addClick()">Crear</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is this possible in angular 2?

Yes, it is possible.

> If both of the conditions are true, will they enable the button?

No, if they are true, then the button will be disabled. `disabled="true"`.

> I try the above code but it's not working well

What did you expect? the button will be disabled when `valid` is false and the angular `formGroup`, `SAForm` is not valid.

A recommendation here as well, Please make the button of type button not a submit because this may cause the whole form to submit and you would need to use `invalidate` and listen to `(ngSubmit)`.

Comment: I expect that if they are both true they will enable the button

Comment: correct, if `valid` is true and the `fromGroup` is valid also, then the button will be enabled.

Comment: You may try the other another answer, or post the html and the ts files so we may a better understanding of what is the `valiad` variable is

Comment: and what will be the code for validation in the button

Comment: I don't understand the question. Please explain it to me.

Answer (score 0):

Button and any other elements can be disabled in the Form based on conditional param defined in the component.
For example:

In the component(typescript) define the boolean field:

```
isTheElementDisabled: boolean;
```

In the template as an element attribute:

```
[disabled]="isTheElementDisabled"
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that in the disabled button there is no option at all to do the operator & there is only an option to do || (or) and it works like && Exactly the same.

Answer (score -2):

Using the ternary operator is possible like following.[disabled] internally required true or false for its operation.

```
<button type="button" 
  [disabled]="(testVariable1 != 0 || testVariable2!=0)? true:false"
  mat-button>Button</button>
```

Comment: Ternary to return a boolean that the condition gives?