# Disable router navigate link based on conditions

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-services, angular-router, angular-route-guards

How can I disable the `router.navigate` or the link, based on a status?

If the status is a "No" then i can't type the link to edit the Materials?

#### HTML

```
<button type="button" (click)="onEditMaterial(material.id)">Edit </button>
```

#### TS

```
onEditMaterial(material_id) {
  this.router.navigate(['materials', material_id, 'edit']);
}
```

Comment: Need more info. It's not clear from description what you want to do.

Comment: Improve formatting of title and removed unnecessary formatting

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable button in angular 2 with two conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43534347/disable-button-in-angular-2-with-two-conditions)

Answer (score -1):

`<button [attr.disable]="status === 'No'">click me</button>`
.`status` is a string in your angular component. `<button [disable]="status === 'No'">click me</button>` syntax.

Edit: `disable` attribute is a HTML5 attribute used for `<input> ,  <button>` etc. You can make it look nicer for better UX with some css as well like this: `button:disabled {cursor: not-allowed;}`

Edit: another way is something like this

```
onEditMaterial(material_id) {
    if (this.status === 'No') return; // if the status is 'No' don't do anything

    this.router.navigate(['materials', material_id, 'edit']);
  }
```

Comment: My problem if the api has given the status? How can i declare it?

Comment: have a `status` property in the component
`public status: string = ''`. Then after you do the `this.http.get(...).toPromise().then((data)=>{//check here the status of the response and change the state of the status to this.status = some_value)` - you can past the code of the service you are talking about

Comment: Can you this instead? <button [attr.disable]="mat_status !== 'No'">EDIT</button>

Comment: sure..if `mat_status` is the property that changes

Comment: But why if my mat_status is yes, the button is always disabled??

Comment: `<button [attr.disable]="mat_status === 'No'">EDIT</button>` - it means if `mat_status` is 'No' disabled it

Comment: How about if mat_status is not equals to No?

Comment: then it's not going to be disabled

Comment: How can i write if mat_status is not equals to No?

Comment: check this online example https://jsfiddle.net/gjvdx37g/ what you are asking is quite simple to be honest

Comment: I did this before and it works. *ngIf="mat_status !== 'No'". But if i convert it to the attr.disabled. All my buttons are disabled?

Comment: only the button that you apply the rule, maybe you missed a `'` or a closing tag

Comment: It doesn't still work. And i can type the link in the url

Comment: I can still type the link in the url.

Comment: Hi, I updated my answer. What you need is quite simple. I would recommend spend some more time going through https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/ and https://angular.io/

Answer (score -1):

To disable the button, you can follow the answer provided by DrNio.
There based upon the conversation in comment, if you also want to prevent navigation even with changing URL in browser then you need to use `Router Guard`. Check an example of AuthGuard here: https://angular.io/guide/router#component-less-route-grouping-routes-without-a-component . Search for `export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate`. You basically need to implement `canActivate` method.