# How to disable Navigation Button in angular?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have a list of buttons from which I navigate to other pages and display other content like a component.

I am trying to keep the button and don't know how to disable that buttons.
allowing user to complete firstcomponent filled data and allow to passon second page,thenafter on third,fourth and fifth.

```
<button class="btn btn-outline-primary" (click)="first()">First</button>
<button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" (click)="second()">Second</button>
<button class="btn btn-outline-danger" (click)="third()">Third</button>
<button class="btn btn-outline-warning" (click)="fourth()">Fourth</button>
<button class="btn btn-outline-dark" (click)="fifth()">Fifth</button>
```

After completion of the first form data submit it should allow to click on the second and other buttons.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable button in angular 2 with two conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43534347/disable-button-in-angular-2-with-two-conditions)

Comment: rohit i want that condition in the navigation if i would of form, i would handled that till now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use property binding on the button's disabled property:

```
<button class="btn btn-outline-secondary"
   (click)="second()"
   [disabled]="someConditionYouDefine">Second</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should consider using different routes for each page. That way you'd be able to define a class for the `routerLinkActive`, and automatically assign a class to the navigation item that is currently active. You can read more on navigation in angular [here](https://angular.io/guide/router).

Without navigation, you can archive this in many ways, but please do not make a function for each nav item. You can set your navigation items, then create a generic navigation function. [Here's a demo.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vbafdt)

component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

type NavigationButton = {
  name : string,
  class : string
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})

export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  navItems : NavigationButton[] = [
    {class : "btn btn-outline-secondary", name: "Second"},
    {class : "btn btn-outline-primary", name: "Third"},
    {class : "btn btn-outline-success", name: "Fourth"},
    {class : "btn btn-outline-danger", name: "Fifth"}
  ]
  selectedButton: NavigationButton

  navigateTo = (button : NavigationButton) => {
    this.selectedButton = button;
  }
}
```

template:

```
<button
  *ngFor="let navItem of navItems"
  [class]="navItem.class"
  [disabled]="selectedButton == navItem"
  (click)="navigateTo(navItem)">
  {{navItem.name}}
</button>
```

Comment: can i share my stackblitz..?